# Postgres is taking too long to attach partition to a table. Want to understand why

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have a table T1(non-partitioned). Size of T1 is approx 4TB. I have created another table T2(partitioned table). Now I want to attach T1 as child table of T2. So I am running below query to achieve the same.

```
ALTER TABLE T1
  ADD CONSTRAINT partition_check_skip 
  CHECK ( "created_at" BETWEEN ( '-infinity' ) 
  AND ( DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE::timestamp) + '7 days'::interval )) NOT VALID;

ALTER TABLE public.T2
  ATTACH PARTITION T1 FOR VALUES FROM 
  ('-infinity') TO (DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE::timestamp) + '7 days'::interval);
```

Even though I have mentioned `NOT VALID`, still Postgres is taking too long to attach T1 as partition of T2.

**Schema of T1**

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  uuid         uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
  created_at   timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE    NOT NULL,
  updated_at   timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE    NOT NULL
);
```

**Schema of T2**

```
CREATE TABLE T2
(
  uuid         uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL,
  created_at   timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE    NOT NULL,
  updated_at   timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE    NOT NULL
) PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
```

Tried adding `NOT VALID` but still it is taking too long.

---

Here are the actual SQL statements:

Non Partitioned Table

```
CREATE TABLE public.random_txn_old (
    id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT id_generator(),
    ref_id text NULL,
    txn_ref_id text NULL,
    msg_id text NULL,
    api text NULL,
    req_payload jsonb NULL,
    res_payload jsonb NULL,
    bi_req jsonb NULL,
    bi_res jsonb NULL,
    status text NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp_utc(),
    modified_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp_utc(),
    is_deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT t2_check CHECK (((created_at >= '2021-02-23 00:00:00') AND (created_at <= '2023-02-24 00:00:00'))),
    CONSTRAINT transaction_old_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
);
CREATE INDEX random_ref_id ON public.random_txn_old USING btree (ref_id);
CREATE INDEX ran_ref_api_idx ON public.random_txn_old USING btree (txn_ref_id, api);
```

Table Triggers:

```
create trigger set_timestamp_txn before
update
    on
    public.random_txn_old for each row execute function trigger_set_timestamp_modify();
```

Partitioned Table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.random_table (
    id int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT id_generator(),
    ref_id text NULL,
    txn_ref_id text NULL,
    msg_id text NULL,
    api text NULL,
    req_payload jsonb NULL,
    res_payload jsonb NULL,
    bi_req jsonb NULL,
    bi_res jsonb NULL,
    status text NULL,
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp_utc(),
    modified_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp_utc(),
    is_deleted bool NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT transaction_part_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at)
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (created_at);
CREATE INDEX random_part_ref_id ON ONLY public.random_table USING btree (ref_id);
CREATE INDEX ran_part_ref_api_idx ON ONLY public.random_table USING btree (txn_ref_id, api);
```

What I trying to do?

Trying to attach random_txn_old to random_table using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE random_table
     ATTACH PARTITION random_txn_old FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-02-23 00:00:00.000')
        TO ('2023-02-24 00:00:00.000');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of conditions that `T1` must fulfill for this to work quickly:

- the table must have indexes that can be used for partitions of all indexes on the partitioned table
- there must be a check constraint that matches the partitioning constraint and (unless the column is defined `NOT NULL`) prohibits NULL values

You created a constraint that matches the partitioning constraint, so make sure that the column is defined `NOT NULL` and validate the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 VALIDATE CONSTRAINT partition_check_skip;
```

That won't block work on the table. Make sure you have all required indexes, then attaching the table as partition should be fast.

---

In your case, the check constraint isn't defined correctly. Instead of

```
created_at <= '2023-02-24 00:00:00'
```

you have to test for the upper end of the range like this:

```
created_at < '2023-02-24 00:00:00'
```

This is because the upper end is not included in range partitioning.

Comment: With this added information, the case is clear.